# Equivalent expression of $p' \cup (p\cap q')$

Tags: boolean-algebra

> The proposition $p' \cup (p\cap q')$ is equivalent to $1.$ $p\cup q'$ $2.$ $p\to q'$ $3.$ $q\to p$ $4.$ $p\cap q'$?

The given expression can be written as $(p'\cup p)\cap (p'\cup q')=1\cap (p'\cup q')=p'\cup q'$

How to proceed further?

Comment: Do you know the definition of implies in logic?

Comment: @ColmBhandal yes, $p\to q\implies p'\cup q$, right?

Comment: @ColmBhandal Oh got it, so, answer should be 2.

Comment: Yep, you got it :)